# how tu run puppeteer chromium/chrome `headless:false` on centos 6/7 server

Tags: centos7, chromium, puppeteer, headless

I am trying to get some info from a website, the data is not available at the initial load so I need it to be loaded into a browser so I can scrape it.

I am using puppeteer. when I run chromium with `headless:false` in my centos 7 server I get this error `(chrome:5006): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:`.

I installed the `xorg-x11-server-Xvfb` and all the dependencies .

The chromium itself runs when `headless:true`, but the site I am trying to open gives `net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`.

How can I tell the chromium to use the Xvfb server?? Is it even possible?

My code :

```
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, args: ['--no-sandbox'] });
    const page    = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://targetdomain/', { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems there was a simpler solution to my problem.

Found the solution here : https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1477

`await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3419.0 Safari/537.36');`